# Nested Futures for FutureBuilder

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a `FutureBuilder` widget that should wait for data from a firestore collection.

```
class MyScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: calendarQuery.getCalendarEntry(dateString),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snap) {
        if (snap.hasData) {
          List<Events> recipe = snap.data;
          return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text("Events"),
            ),
            body: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                ...,
              ],
            ),
          );
        } else {
          return LoadingScreen();
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I retrieve a list of events and then for each event I need to fetch some additional details. I tried to do nested Futures and came up with the code below. It generates a `Future<Iterable<Future<Detail>>>` which ends up as `MappedListIterable<DocumentSnapshot,Future<Recipe>>` in `snap.data` and i cannot handle it.

```
class CalendarQuery<T> {
  ...

  Future<Iterable<Future<Detail>>> getCalendarEntry(String date, String type) async {
    return await ref
        .where("date", isEqualTo: date)
        .getDocuments()
        .then((data) {
      return data.documents.map((doc) => Document<Details>(path: 'detailCollection/${doc.data["Event"]["SomeId"]}')
                .getData());
    });
  }
}
```

I think I went wrong here at some points with handling the futures and there is probably a proper way to do this.

Does someone know a way to refactor `getCalendarEntry` so that it returns a `Future<List<T>>`? Or maybe there is a better approach to solve this?

Comment: I assume you are trying to get a Future that completes once all Futures in that `Iterable` complete? Have you tried `Future.wait` ?

Comment: Yes, that might be exactly what i need. Where would i put the `Future.wait`?EDIT: Figured it out, had to put it here: `return Future.wait(data.documents.map((doc) =>_db.document('recipesV2/${doc.data["meal"]["recipeId"]}').get()));`. Works like a charm. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Future.wait` to create a Future that completes once all Futures from an `Iterable` have completed.

In your scenario, you would replace `return await ref` with `return Future.wait(ref` and a closing bracket where needed, to create a Future that waits for all `Details` to be retrieved.